# What exactly is the difference between skip and break in PROMELA?

Tags: model, promela, spin

Let's say I have this piece of PROMELA code

```
active proctype A(){

   do
      :: !x -> break
      :: else -> skip
   od

   … //more code
}
```

What exactly does `break` and `skip` do in this instance? Does `break` break out the whole process `A()` so that "more code" wouldn't be reached or just the loop?

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Why would I deal with the whole sign in process to this site if I didn't really needed help? There is information out there but it wasn't clear to me yet… So I was hoping that someone could explain it to me in simple words.  Comments like yours aren't really helping anyone.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

- **break**: an (always executable) instruction which makes the execution jump at the end of the innermost loop in which it is contained. This type of instruction is pretty much universal for pretty much any programming language.
- **skip**: an empty (always executable) instruction that has no effect. There are plenty of *no-op* examples from other languages, like `pass` in `python`, `;` (and others) in `C`, `jQuery.noop()` in `jQuery`, etc.

---

```
active proctype A(){

   do
      :: !x -> break
      :: else -> skip
   od

   … //more code
}
```

In this instance, as soon as `x` becomes false then `break` forces the loop to terminate, whereas `skip` is just an empty instruction to explicitly represent the fact that in the other case the loop keeps doing nothing.

---

From [the docs of **break**](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/break.html)

> **NAME**
>
> break - jump to the end of the innermost do loop.
>
> [...]
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> ```
> L1: do
>     :: t1 -> t2
>     :: t3 -> break
>     :: break
>     od;
> L2: ...
> ```
>
> In this example, control reaches the label L1 immediately after statement t2 is executed. Control can also reach label L2 immediately after statement t3 is executed, and optionally, in one execution step, control can also move from label L1 to label L2.

From [the docs of **skip**](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/skip.html)

> **NAME**
>
> skip - shorthand for a dummy, nil statement.
>
> [...]
>
> **EXAMPLES**
>
> ```
> proctype A()
> {
> L0:   if
>       :: cond1 -> goto L1 /* jump to end */
>       :: else -> skip     /* skip redundant */
>       fi;
>       ...
>
> L1:   skip
> }
> ```
>
> The skip statement that follows label L1 is required in this example. The use of the skip statement following the else guard in the selection structure above is redundant. The above selection can be written more tersely as:
>
> ```
> L0:   if 
>       :: cond1 -> goto L1
>       :: else
>       fi;
> ```
>
> Because *Promela* is an asynchronous language, the skip is never needed, nor effective, to introduce delay in process executions. In *Promela*, by definition, there can always be an arbitrary, and unknowable, delay between any two subsequent statement executions in a proctype body. This semantics correspond to the *golden rule* of concurrent systems design that forbids assumptions about the relative execution speed of asynchronous processes in a concurrent system.